# 3D plots with standard x,y,z-axes

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm new to Mathematica. I'm trying to figure out how to do 3D plots that show the standard x, y, z-axes instead of a rectangle box on the outside. I looked through Wolfram's online documentation, but I was not able figure out the options/parameters needed to make this happen.

Comment: use the options `Boxed -> False`, `Axes -> True`, and `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}`?

Answer (score 1):

to do it you can set the option Boxed with value false in your Plot3D function.

```
Plot3D[{4 + x^2 - y^2, -4 - x^2 + y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", FaceGrids -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

Example:
[image]